# c# ternary operator multiple if else condition

Tags: c#

I have the following c# ternary operator:

```
 CrossConnectionProg = rdCrossConnectionProg.SelectedValue == "1" 
                         ? true 
                         : rdCrossConnectionProg.SelectedValue == "0" 
                              ? false 
                              : (bool?)null;
```

**Note that CrossConnecytionProg is a nullable boolean.**

What I am trying do is check the value of the radio button (rdCrossConnectionProg). If it is "1" then I like to assign true. Else if it is "0", I like to assign it false. If it is neither, I like to assign it a null value.

When I do the following, if nothing is selected, it becomes false instead of null.

Comment: Before calling your operator, try `Debug.WriteLine(rdCrossConnectionProg.SelectedValue);` to know what your value is. I have a strong feeling that it's "0" when nothing is selected.

Comment: This might be a noob question, but what radio button class are you using? I cannot find "SelectedValue" in System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton nor System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton nor System.Windows.Controls.RadioButton

Comment: What is the declared type (compile-time type) of the `SelectedValue` property? If it is `object`, you may get an unintended reference-equality comparison. You should see a compiler warning in that case. However, I think that would lead to the opposite problem of what you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What don't you use a more simpler expression? Why not this? -

```
CrossConnectionProg = rdCrossConnectionProg.SelectedValue == "1";
```

Comment: This would never result in a `null` value as intended.